# Multiply every nth field...elegantly

Tags: awk, sed, terminal, xargs

I have a text file with a series of numbers:

`1 2 4 2 2 6 3 4 7 4 4 8 2 4 6 5 5 8`

I need to have every third field multiplied by 3, so output would be:

`1 2 12 2 2 18 3 4 21 4 4 24 2 4 18 5 5 24`

Now, I've hammered out a solution already, but I know there's a quicker, more elegant one out there. Here's what I've gotten to work:

`xargs -n1 < input.txt | awk '{printf NR%3 ? "%d " : $0*3" ", $1}' > output.txt`

I feel that there must be an `awk` one-liner that can do this?? How can I make `awk` look at each field (instead of each record), thus not needing the call to `xargs` to put every field on a different line? Or maybe `sed` can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '{for (i=3;i<=NF;i+=3)$i*=3; print}' input.txt > output.txt
```

I have not tested this yet (posted on my iPod). The `print` command without parameters should print out the whole (partially modified) line. You might have to set `OFS=" "` in the `BEGIN` section to get the blank as the separator in the output.

Comment: +1, would work just fine and it's clear. You don't need to set `OFS=" "` as that's the default.

Answer (score 4):

this line would work too:

```
awk -v RS="\\n| " -v ORS=" " '!(NR%3){$0*=3}7' file
```

Comment: Nice one! This would return all values on a single line. But did you not leave out a `print` command? I assume the `7` is just a typo?

Comment: @cars10 `7` was not a typo. you can try removing it from the command, to see what happens

Comment: I am intrigued to find out by myself but unfortunately I am travelling  'light' and cannot try it out on my iPod :-( Can you pls explain what the `7` does? :)

Comment: @cars10 for a non-zero number (`1, 2 or 7`) awk would do `print` by default. so the `7` will print the current line.

Comment: thanks! Not necessarily easy to read but certainly elegant! +1!

Comment: +1 You should mention it's gawk-only courtesy of the multi-char RS though. Also, instead of `RS="\\n| "` you could use `RE='[[:space:]]'` if you like so it works for any white space and setting `ORS=RT` on each record would avoid adding the trailing blank char, e.g. `gawk -v RS='[[:space:]]' '!(NR%3){$0*=3;ORS=RT}7'`

Comment: @EdMorton, your `gawk` solution works, thanks! @Kent, for some reason your answer just copied the file field for field, no multiplication of every third entry...